# Using substr to find nearby characters

Tags: c++, splice

So I'm trying to find characters within X amount of distance away from each character I'm iterating through. So for an example ....

```
nearby("abcdefg", 2)
```

Should return a set with each character as a key and its values close by within a distance of 2. It should look like this...

```
dictionary('a' -> set(a, b, c), 'b' -> set(a, b, c, d), 'c' -> set(a,b,c,d,e))
```

My code right now looks like this ...

```
dictionary<char, set<char>> near(const std::string word, int dist) {
    dictionary<char, set<char>> map;
    for (int x = 0; x < word.size(); x++) {
        for (char letter : word.substr(std::max(0, x - dist), std::min(dist + 1, int(word.size()))))
            map[word[x]].insert(letter);
    }
    return map;
}
```

**Outline of the issue:**
- It works for the most part, however, because of C++'s substring I can't specify that I want all characters from index 0 to 4. Instead, it indexes at 0, and then includes anything within a range of 4. This is problematic when I want to go backwards to include characters 4 letters in the front **and** in the back.

As of now, my code will be correct, but leave one character off at the end. So it looks like this instead ...

```
nearby(abcdefg, 2)
dictionary('c' -> set(a,b,c))
```

It leaves out d.

Comment: What is this class "dictionary"?  Is it just `std::map`?  If so, please write that.  Also, you refer to `std::min` but just `set`.  Is that `std:set`?  If not, what is it?

Comment: I suppose you could assume that; they're custom classes I made, but I thought that was irrelevant to the problem itself. Just know that they operate the way dictionaries and sets work normally. They work fine; the issue is the splicing of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need:

```
        const auto start = std::max(0, x-dist);
        const auto end = std::min(x+dist+1, int(word.size());
        const auto len = end - start;
        const auto substring = word.substr(start,len);
        auto &the_set = map[word[x]];
        for (const auto letter : substring)
            the_set.insert(letter);
```

As noted in the comments, this will break if `word.size()` > `INT_MAX`.  The solution is do everything in `size_t` (you *could* do it all in `std::string::size_t` but that is ridiculously verbose, and doesn't really buy you anything).

```
dictionary<char, set<char>> near(const std::string word, size_t dist) {
    dictionary<char, set<char>> map;
    for (size_t x = 0; x < word.size(); x++) {
        const auto start = (x > dist) ? x-dist : 0;  // Beware underflow
        const auto end = std::min(x+dist+1, word.size());
        const auto len = end - start;
        const auto substring = word.substr(start,len);
        auto &the_set = map[word[x]];
        for (const auto letter : substring)
            the_set.insert(letter);
     }
 }
```

This version has the advantage that gcc will compile it with `-Werror -Wall` (the previous version would have complained about signed/unsigned comparison), and doesn't have a cast (always a good sign).

Even better would be a version where `start` and `end` were iterators into `word` - at which point you wouldn't need to create the substring *at all* (you could just look at the characters in the original word).

Comment: My second favorite keyword is `auto`; my favourite is `const`.  You'd never guess, would you?

Comment: `std::min(x+dist+1, int(word.size());` this will break if `std::string::size_type`  has a greater max then `int`

Comment: I think it will actually only break if `word.size()` is greater than INT_MAX (which is clearly only possible if `std::string::size_type`has a greater max than `int`, but is a much stronger condition).  The breakage is also present in the original code.

Comment: You're an absolute delight. I feel so dumb for not coming up with the difference in lengths. I kept trying to do some splice maneuver.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes that is correct.  What I meant to say is that if `std::string::size_type` can hold values larger than an `int` then this will break if the `string.size() > INT_MAX`